# Having issues with multiple div elements in a static website

Tags: html, css

I am having a div element which has an image in it. I also have other div elements positioned on top of this div element. The issue is that without these div elements, the top part of the image is visible. But when these other div elements are added, they seem to be getting into the space of this image and the top 30% of the image is kind of hidden which gets exposed only when we scroll up. I don't understand why the other divs are taking the space of this div element. Code is as follows:

```
.image-div{
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 1970px 850px;
  background-image: url("test.jpg");
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
}

#top-content{
  width: 100%;
}

#top-content-line1{
  margin-left: 130px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#border-top{
  border-top: 1px solid;
  border-top-color: lightgrey;
  padding-bottom: 15px;
}

#menu-item{
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li{
  display:inline;
    float: left;
  padding-right: 150px;
}

#first-element{
  padding-left: 150px;
}


<div id="top-content">
    <p id="top-content-line1">address line1, line 2, pincode
        <br> <span id="restoname">NAME </span> 
    </p>
</div>
<div id="border-top"> </div>
<div id="menu-item">
  <ul>
    <li id="first-element"><a href="">Home</a></li> 
    <li><a href=" ">Our Vision</a></li> 
    <li><a href=" ">Menu</a></li> 
    <li><a href=" ">Order Online</a></li> 
    <li><a href=" ">Contact Us</a></li> 
  </ul> 
</div>
<div class="image-div"></div>
```

If I remove the div elements above "topfixedimg" then the image seems to occupy larger space. Otherwise, the top div elements seems to be chopping the image in this div, which becomes clear only when we scroll the webpage.

Comment: Your CSS doesn't correspond to your HTML in a meaningful way (e.g., where is `.imagediv` in your HTML or `.topfixedimg` in your CSS?). Can you build a working demo in Codepen or a similar site to show your issue?

Comment: doyourselfafavorandputsomedashesinuyouridsandclassnames

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dJaGPW I have it on codepen here. 
We can see that the div elements above the image's div have kind of occupied the image's div. As we scroll up, we can see the image's top part. My question is since this div that contains the image is below all these divs, shouldn't the image be starting after all the other divs end ?

Comment: The height of the div is 500px and the height of the background is 850px, so naturally, some cutoff happens. In this case, both from the top and from the bottom. And if the user scrolls, more is cut off from the bottom and less from the top. Does that explain what happens?